# How many possible arrangements if position i cannot be ai?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a problem for programming, but I think there might be an analytical solution. The problem description goes as follows.

There are N apples and N bags. We need to put each apple in one of the bags, and each bag can only contain one apple. Each bag $i$ has a number $a_i$ on it, which states that $a_i$-th apple cannot be put into $i$-th bag. So how many different arrangements that fulfill these restriction?

Any hint is welcomed.

Comment: These are *derangements*

Comment: @Henry uhm... not necessarily.  As I understand it, the $a_i$'s don't need to be unique.  If they were, then it would be a derangement (*a derangement with respect to the permutation described by the $a_i$'s*).  On the other extreme, if every $a_i$ was the number $1$, then no arrangements would be possible since we would have no legal place to put apple $1$ into.

Comment: @JMoravitz I had assumed the $a_i$ were the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ in some permutation.  If $a_i=n+1$ for all $i$ then there are $n!$ valid arrangements, but I doubt that possibility was the original intention

Comment: And that is quite a big assumption that they appear as a permutation with no repeated values, one which if true would lead to a nice solution.  Given that it isn't mentioned in the problem statement and given that the problem originated as a programming challenge, it seems reasonable to assume otherwise.  If we were to allow the $a_i$'s to not necessarily be unique, the general problem increases in difficulty quite dramatically and it makes sense that the intended best solution is via brute force and programming.  In the end, this should be clarified by the OP.

Comment: A completely unhelpful answer is, the desired number is the permanent of a matrix $A$, all of whose entries are $1$ except for the $(i,a_i)$ entries, which are $0$.